# CSS scale transformation on iOS Safari zooms page out

Tags: ios, css, safari, transform

I'm trying to have a snippet of text "zoom & fade in" once the page is loaded. To do so, I'm creating a div with the text inside and setting it to transform immediately:

```
.whatIwantZoomed {
  opacity:0;

    /* Vendor Prefixes here */
  transform:scale(4,4);

    /* Vendor Prefixes here */
  transition:transform 1s, opacity 1s;
}
```

Now, when called from my Javascript function, an `animated` class is applied which reduces the scale  to `(1,1)`:

```
.whatIwantZoomed.animated {
  opacity:1;

    /* Vendor Prefixes here */
  transform:scale(1,1);
 }
```

Now, on mobile Safari (both iOS 7 & iOS 8), the effect actually does work. **The problem** is the scaled text is actually larger than the width of the viewport, causing it to 'resize' and zoom the page out. As the animation occurs, the page resizes back to how it should be.

What I'm trying to do here is remove this unwanted viewport width alteration. I've tried setting the body to have a property of `overflow-x:hidden;` to no avail, and I can't seem to get the viewport metatag to help me either.

Can anyone shed some light on a solution here? Thanks.

EDIT: [Added a fiddle demonstrating this](http://jsfiddle.net/LukasNZ/t8cc387u/). Notice the scrollbars in the HTML frame? That's what I'm trying to prevent.

Comment: are you using `transform-style: preserve-3d` on te parent? and can you please make a fiddle?

Comment: @Tambo added a fiddle. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t8cc387u/1/)

```
div {
    text-align:center;
    background-color:red;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform:perspective(1200) scale(1);
    animation:animated 1s ease-in-out;    
}

@keyframes animated{
    from{transform:scale(10);opacity:0}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this, it seems to be related to [this bug](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13510)

The root cause is things that are off screen incorrectly trigger safari (or wkwebview) to resize the viewport.

Add this to your viewport meta tag:

`shrink-to-fit=no`